# AngularJS directive: is it possible to interpolate within an attribute?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got a directive I call as follows:

```
<photos ng-if="sp.photoZoom" class="alignRight"
    photoid="{{hs.id}}-{{hs.name}}"
    list="[{file: 'rsc/drive/4-Semis/{{hs.id}}-{{hs.name}}/{{hs.tabs[0].photo}}'}]"
    size="256px"
    extension="jpg">
</photos>
```

It sounds the list and photos are not being interpolated.

What should I do?

[edit]
The directive:

```
app.directive("photos", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            "photoid": "@",
            "scrollable": "@",
            "size": "@",
            "list": "=",
            "inline": "@",
            "extension": "@",
            "class": "@"
        },
        template: 
        '<div id="photos{{photoid}}" class="scroller {{class}}" ng-class="[{{scrollable}}]" ng-style="{display:list.length==1?\'inline-block\':\'block\', width: list.length==1?\'{{size?size:\'171px\'}}\':\'auto\', height: \'{{size?size:\'171px\'}}\'}">\n\
            <div ng-repeat="p in list"\n\
                ng-style="{\'background-image\': \'url({{p.file}}.thumb.{{extension}})\', width: \'{{size?size:\'171px\'}}\', height: \'{{size?size:\'171px\'}}\'}"\n\
                ng-click="$parent.$parent.openPopoverImageViewer(\'#photos{{photoid}}\', {{$index}})">\n\
                <div>{{p.text}}</div>\n\
            </div>\n\
        </div>'
    };
});
```

Comment: It depends how the directive handles its attributes. Can we the definition of the directive?

Comment: The previous answer was the solution

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca is 'photos' your own directive? does it have an isolated scope?

Comment: Yes it is @Josep I just added it to the question.

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca check my answer then, now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the list parameter (=) requires one has to angularize it (as follows):

```
<photos
    photoid="{{hs.id}}-{{hs.name}}"
    list="[{file: 'rsc/drive/4-Semis/'+hs.id+'-'+hs.name+'/'+hs.tabs[0].photo, text:hs.tabs[0].displayName}]"
    size="256px"
    extension="jpg">
</photos>
```